# PDF documents don't open inside fancybox in mobile devices, so I don't want to open a blank fancybox when I click to open PDFs in these devices

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I'm using fancybox to open PDFs. It is working fine on desktop but in mobile and tablets fancybox is not opening PDFs.

And I already did some research and it seems that fancybox definitely does not work on mobile devices.

So I want to know if it is possible to show my "class="fancybox_pdf" in my link only when my website is accessed by a desktop or laptop.

```
<a class="fancybox_pdf" href="<?php echo BASE.'/documents/pdfs/test1.pdf'?>">Link for pdf</a>
```

On mobile devices I don't want to open my PDF documents inside fancybox, because it doesn't work, so I also don't want to open a blank fancybox that is what is happening.

Do you know if it is possible do this?

I try with CSS like:

```
<a class="fancybox_pdf" href="<?php echo BASE.'/documents/pdfs/test1.pdf'?>">Link for pdf</a>
<a  href="<?php echo BASE.'/documents/pdfs/test1.pdf'?>">Link for pdf</a>

@media screen and (min-width:981px) { .fancybox_pdf:{display:none;}}
```

But it doesn't work ok, because I have this media query that gets laptops but also tablets, and I just don't want to open my PDFs inside fancybox on mobile devices, for laptops I want to open because works fine.

This is my link:

```
<a class="fancybox_pdf" href="<?php echo BASE.'/documents/pdfs/test1.pdf'?>">Link for pdf</a>
```

And my script:

```
$(".fancybox_pdf").fancybox({
    width: '80%',
    height: '80%',
    autoSize: false,
    type: 'iframe',
    iframe: {
        preload: false
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is to assign a different *class* to the link so I can manipulate it independently from the *class* `fancybox_pdf` like

```
<a class="pdf" href="<?php echo BASE.'/documents/pdfs/test1.pdf'?>">Link for pdf</a>
```

Then validate if you are using a mobile device (along with the screen `width` optionally) and add or remove the *class* `fancybox_pdf` accordingly like :

```
// detect mobile devices by features
var isTouchSupported = 'ontouchstart' in window,
isTouchSupportedIE10 = navigator.userAgent.match(/Touch/i) != null,
_isMobile = (isTouchSupported || isTouchSupportedIE10) ? true : false;

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // optionally validates screen width
    if (_isMobile && jQuery(window).innerWidth() < 768) {
        // mobile devices most likely
        if (jQuery(".pdf").hasClass("fancybox_pdf")) {
            jQuery(".pdf").removeClass("fancybox_pdf");
        };
    } else {
        // desktop devices most likely
        if (!jQuery(".pdf").hasClass("fancybox_pdf")) {
            jQuery(".pdf").addClass("fancybox_pdf");
        };
    };
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rf6b2nqw/)**

**Note** : you still need to keep your script

```
$(".fancybox_pdf").fancybox();
```